# How do I access ext3 journal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, ext3

> I want to recover a deleted file by ext3 journal. How to access ext3 journal?

Comment: This question is probably better on ServerFault (http://serverfault.com/) or SuperUser

Comment: Unable to find @TimCroydon

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow the instruction on

http://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/06/29/restoring-deleted-files-from-the-ext3-journal/